# Exchange 2016 - export all mailboxes and their properties, error?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, exchange-server

I need to export the below groups DisplayName SamAccountName PrimarySMTPAddress **Imap Enabled/Disabled Pop Enable/Disable OWA Enable/Disable Active Sync Enable/Disable**
and Im stuck with trying to get the status for the each of the 4 objects....I have the scrip to show in grid but eventually will export to csv, I just want to make it work first.

Can someone help?

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Select-Object DisplayName, SamAccountName, PrimarySmtpAddress, Imap, Pop, OWA, ActiveSync | Sort-Object PrimarySmtpAddress | Out-GridView
```

Comment: You've not included the error that you are getting.

Comment: thanks Tom, the error is that nothing shows up in for Imap, Pop, owa and active sync....I Only get results for - Displaname, SamAcc and Pirmary smtp....

how do I pull the data out for each mailbox ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-CasMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited |
Select-Object DisplayName, SamAccountName, PrimarySmtpAddress, Imapenabled, Popenabled, OWAEnabled, ActiveSyncenabled |
Sort-Object PrimarySmtpAddress |
Export-Csv C:\Users\fis_da01\Desktop\Exchange2016_Exports.Exchange_Settings_7_19_2022.csv
```

Comment: Tom, thanks I figured it out! Run that in Management Shell....

Answer (score 0):

Get-CASMailbox -Filter {ActiveSyncEnabled -eq $true} | Select-Object DisplayName,PrimarySmtpAddress

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).